# How to customize an LSTM loss function to only concider a given index range of prediction and target sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am currently working with an LSTM sequence to sequence model for time domain signal predictions. Because of domain knowledge, I know that the first part of the prediction (about 20%) can never be predicted correctly, since the information required is not available in the given input sequence. The remaining 80% of the predicted sequence are usually predicted quite well. In order to exclude the first 20% from the training optimization, it would be nice to define a loss function that would basically operate on a given index range like the numpy code below:

```
start = int(0.2*sequence_length)
stop = sequence_length

def mse(pred, target):
    """ Mean squared error between two time series np.arrays """
    return 1/target.shape[0]*np.sum((pred-target)**2)

def range_mse_loss(y_pred, y):
    return mse(y_pred[start:stop],y[start:stop])
```

How do I have to write this loss function in order to have it work with my preexisting keras code, where loss is simply given by `model.compile(loss='mse')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice your tensor to just last 80% of the data.

```
size = int(y_true.shape[0] * 0.8) # for 2D vector, e.g., (100, 1)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(name='mse')

loss_fn(y_pred[:-size], y_true[:-size])
```

You can also use the sample_weights at the tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), passing an array of weights and the first 20% of weights is zero

```
size = int(y_true.shape[0] * 0.8) # for 2D vector, e.g., (100, 1)

zeros = tf.zeros((y_true.shape[0] - size), dtype=tf.int32)
ones = tf.ones((size), dtype=tf.int32)

weights = tf.concat([zeros, ones], 0)

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(name='mse')

loss_fn(y_pred, y_true, sample_weights=weights)
```

There is a warming of the second solution, the final loss will be lower than the first solution, because you are putting zero in the first predictions values, but you aren't removing them in the formula MSE = 1 /n * sum((y-y_hat)^2).

Comment: since 0s affect `mse` value, I wonder is there a reason for not using `masking` and selection of values based upon this `mask`?

Comment: Hi @AtherCheema, I agree with you, can you answer the question with the option of using mask?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to mark the observations as None/nan and then  overwrite the `train_step` method. Following tensorflow's [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) about customizing `train_step`, you would do something like this

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(keras_model, data):
    print('custom train_step')
    # Unpack the data. Its structure depends on your model and
    # on what you pass to `fit()`.
    x, y = data

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = keras_model(x, training=True)  # Forward pass

        # masking nan values in observations, also assuming that targets are >0.0
        mask = tf.greater(y, 0.0)
        true_y = tf.boolean_mask(y, mask)
        pred_y = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, mask)

        # Compute the loss value
        # (the loss function is configured in `compile()`)
        loss = keras_model.compiled_loss(true_y, pred_y, regularization_losses=keras_model.losses)

    # Compute gradients
    trainable_vars = keras_model.trainable_variables
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)
    # Update weights
    keras_model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
    # Update metrics (includes the metric that tracks the loss)
    keras_model.compiled_metrics.update_state(true_y, pred_y)
    # Return a dict mapping metric names to current value
    return {m.name: m.result() for m in keras_model.metrics}
```

This will work for all the performance metrics you are tracking. Alternative way would be to mask the nans inside the loss function but that would be limited to only one loss function and not any other loss function/performance metrics.